# particularly one routerlink not working in angular 7

Tags: angular, routes, angular-material, angular-routing, angular7

I am using angular 7 with material framework. I was working on Menus through router and actually it's working but one link is not registering. I did added it in Module and route also. I have attached my rendered DOM below:
[image]

And this is my AppComponent.ts content

```
<mat-nav-list class="sidenav-submenu" *ngIf="showMenu">
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/BlockMaster"><fa name="building"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Block Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/FloorMaster"><fa name="building"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Floor Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/CellMaster"><fa name="lock"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cell Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerlink="/LocatorMaster"><fa name="location-arrow"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Locator Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/TagMaster"><fa name="tags"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tag Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/TagMember"><fa name="users"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Member Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/VisitorConfRoom"><fa name="street-view"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Visitor Conf Room Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/PrisonerConfRoom"><fa name="university"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Prisoner Conf Room Master</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/MapLocator"><fa name="university"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Map Locator</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/TagTracker"><fa name="university"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tag Tracker</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

And my Route config is below:

```
 Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'CellMaster', component: CellMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'TagMaster', component: TagMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'TagMember', component: TagMemberComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'LocatorMaster', component: LocatorMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'BlockMaster', component: BlockMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'FloorMaster', component: FloorMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'VisitorConfRoom', component: VisitorConfRoomMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'PrisonerConfRoom', component: PrisonerConfRoomMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'MapLocator', component: MapLocatorComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'TagTracker', component: TagTrackerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }];
```

I am not sure what's the issue.

Comment: can you provide a basic stack blitz demo, to understand more on this.

Comment: With the same code, it's working now. I think, after importing routingComponents in appmodule. I am unsure about the scenario, will check and update here later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try add `routerLinkActive="active"` to your a tags

**example:**

```
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/BlockMaster" routerLinkActive="active">
    <fa name="building"></fa>&nbsp;&nbsp;Block Master
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote wrong.  `router[l]ink="/LocatorMaster"` => `router[L]ink="/LocatorMaster"`